# Multiple Patterns for Regex Expression MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to get a MongoDB aggregate pipeline working. I need to match name to "John" and regex their "hometown" field to regex matching "CAPETOWN" or "FLORIDA" without case sensitivity. Basically if either of those patterns exist in the "hometown" field of the document. This is what I have so far.

```
        const news = await cachedDb.collection(COLLECTION).aggregate([
        { $match: { "name": "John", "hometown": { $regex: /CAPETOWN/, $options: 'i' } } }
      ]).toArray();
```

I can only get CAPETOWN included, I want an OR. Such as "hometown" contains CAPETOWN OR FLORIDA with option (i). How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set OR directly in the regex string.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "hometown": {
        $regex: "CAPETOWN|FLORIDA",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_-GWWIjMNgy)